# Front-end pages messed up due to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, apache, configuration, virtual-hosts

I have a WP blog at https://example.com/blog. I'm able to access the wp-admin pages but the front-end pages are messed up (https://example.com/blog/page/2/). I have `/blog` set as an alias in my Apache VirtualHosts configuration file. It was working fine before I switched on HTTPS through Cloudflare.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/keys/example.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/keys/example.key

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/master

    <Directory "/var/www/html/example/master">
        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    Alias /blog /var/www/html/example/blog
    <Directory /var/www/html/example/blog>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you contacted with Cloudflare's support?

Comment: This means you CAN access the front-end pages, they just seem to be messed up.